# I don't think anyone/anything ... where to negate?

Tags: grammaire, négation, subordonnées

I know that 'I haven't seen anyone' is 'Je n'ai vu personne', but how would you translate 'I don't think I saw anyone'?

One solution that comes to mind is 'Je pense que je n'ai vu personne', but does it feel unnatural to say 'I think I didn't see anyone/ I saw nobody'? How about more complicated sentences like 'I don't think any of Camus' novels inspired any of my friends' or 'I don't think anybody said anything was immoral'?

Answer (score 5):

La réponse générale est d'utiliser:

> quiconque / qui que ce soit (*pour une personne*).
>
> une quelconque chose
>   / quoi que ce soit (*pour une chose*).

**I don't think I saw anyone.**

> Je ne pense pas que j'ai vu qui que ce soit *(plutôt laid)*.

Raccourci en:

> Je ne pense pas avoir vu qui que ce soit.
>
> Je ne pense pas avoir vu quiconque.

**I don't think any of Camus novels inspired any of my friends.**

> Je ne pense pas qu'une quelconque nouvelle de Camus ait inspiré un de
>   mes amis.

**I don't think anybody said anything was immoral**

> Je ne pense pas que qui que ce soit qui ait dit quoi ce soit, soit
>   immoral.

Comment: J'ai l'impression qu'il manque quelquechose dans la phrase "Je ne pense pas avoir vu quiconque.". Il me semble qu'il faudrait que la phrase soit complétée par "Je ne pense pas avoir vu quiconque défier son autorité." par exemple. J'ai une mauvaise impression quand la phrase se termine aussi vite, je ne suis pas sûr qu'on puisse utiliser quiconque dans ce cas... Quelqu'un à la même impression ?